# Display image via local path - file:\\\c:\ using PHP

Tags: php

I want to load image via `c:/user_name/image/image_name.jpg` using `http://intranet/user/index.php`.

```
<img src="file:///c:/user_name/image/image_name.jpg">
```

How do I display them?

Thanks
Jean

Comment: I do accept answers, provided there is a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote, I love it. :)

Answer (score 5):

You realize this would only work if that image is in the exact same location on every machine which will be viewing this page? Is there any reason you can't serve up the image normally, via the web server itself?

Since you're using an absolute Windows path, this would only work on Windows machines, which actually have a C drive, the same directories, etc... It won't work at all on a Mac or Linux or whatever else box, since they don't bother with drive letters.

followup:

after pondering your question a bit, it looks like you want to serve up a specific image that's not stored in your document root and serve it from a specific page. If you put something like this at the start of your index.php:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['username']) && isset($_GET['image'])) {
       $user = $_GET['username'];
       $image = $_GET['image'];

       $path = "C:\\{$user}\\image\\{$image}";
       if (is_readable($path)) {
           $info = getimagesize($path);
           if ($info !== FALSE) {
               header("Content-type: {$info['mime']}");
               readfile($path);
               exit();
           }
       }
    }
?>
```

and within the HTML:

```
<img src="index.php?user=user_name&image=image_name" />
```

Of course, this is very basic, and serving up files this way is highly insecure, but most likely this is the basics of what you wanted.

Comment: does not work, tried the same thing.  You will observe my question, the image tag <img src="file:///c:/user_name/image/image_name.jpg">.  It does not work, therefore approached stackoverflow.

Comment: Of course it won't work. `file:///`  will always try to load the file from the LOCAL computer. If you're serving a site from machine A, and someone's browsing it from machine B, the browser will try to find that file on machine B. Like I said in the first part of my answer, this would only ever work if that specific path and file existed on every machine trying to view the site.

Comment: leaving the path out, the image does not show with our without the file:/// or //

Comment: Assuming I am trying to show up images from my local server, it does not show.  If http://localhost/index.php has the simple code <img src="c:/user_name/image/image_name.jpg">, it does not show.  Can you resolve this.

Comment: There's also browser security systems as well. It's highly dangerous to allow "foreign" content to directly access/load data off local drives. In Firefox, what you're attempting to do produces `Security Error: Content at http://panic/test.html may not load or link to file:///c:/test.jpg.`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
   $path = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Create.jpg";       
   if (is_readable($path)) 
   {
       $info = getimagesize($path);
       if ($info !== FALSE) 
       {
           header("Content-type: {$info['mime']}");
           readfile($path);
           echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($path) .'" height="100" width="100"/>';    
       }       
  }
```

?>